# Find strings with several exclude-constraints on the beginning of the line

Tags: grep, regular-expression

If I want to find all the "double-quoted" strings in files, I would use:

```
grep -rnw . -e "\".*\""
```

but I want to exclude all the lines that begin with some text. For example:

- `#include`
- `Serial.`

Example, given these lines:

```
#include "patterns.h"
#include "network.h"
Serial.println("clear");
Serial.println("set wifi");
#include "patterns.h"
#include "common.h"
Serial.printf("[LED] Init segment #%u with size %u\r\n", i + 1, len);
password = "xxxxxx";
ESPAsync_wifiManager.setCredentials(WM_config.WiFi_Creds.wifi_ssid, WM_config.WiFi_Creds.wifi_pw, "", "");
ESPAsync_wifiManager.setCORSHeader("Your Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
Serial.print(F("Starting configuration portal @ "));
Serial.print(F("192.168.4.1"));
```

only these should be listed by the `grep` command:

```
password = "xxxxxx";
ESPAsync_wifiManager.setCredentials(WM_config.WiFi_Creds.wifi_ssid, WM_config.WiFi_Creds.wifi_pw, "", "");
ESPAsync_wifiManager.setCORSHeader("Your Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use PCREs, they support negative look-aheads:

```
grep -Pe '^(?!Serial|#).*".*"'
```

- `^` is the beginning of a line;
- `(?!...)` is the negative look-ahead, i.e. here it means *the line doesn't start with `Serial` nor `#`*

Comment: Running this in Ubuntu 23.04 leads to no output. The command runs, but no output is shown. It's different when it does not match nothing: the prompt immediately shows the usual `name@hostname:path` prefix

Comment: @Mark: Maybe you forgot to provide the input file name?

Comment: You're right, I didn't understand that. Anyway, it excludes the lines that begin with `#` but not the ones that begin with `Serial`

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 22.04 

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed` or `awk` for that:

```bash
sed '/^#/d; /^Serial\./d; /".*"/!d' < your-file
```

```bash
awk  '! /^(Serial\.|#)/ && /".*"/' < your-file
```

Those return the lines that contain at least two `"` characters and start with neither `Serial.` nor `#`.

Note that they also return lines such as:

```c
  Serial.whatever("Serial. not at the beginning");
foo(); // some "comment"
/* and "some"
  "other" comment */
bar('"', '"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed` or compatible:

```
$ sed -En '/^(#|Serial)/!{/".*"/p}' input_file
password = "xxxxxx";
ESPAsync_wifiManager.setCredentials(WM_config.WiFi_Creds.wifi_ssid, WM_config.WiFi_Creds.wifi_pw, "", "");
ESPAsync_wifiManager.setCORSHeader("Your Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the `-v` (`--invert-match`) flag, for excluding lines you *don't* want, and pipe the grep commands together:

`grep -v "^#include" | grep -v "^Serial\." | grep -rnw . -e "\".*\""`